# Update the row if value matches else Insert a new row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a table for student to insert for Entrance Exam  for with following value(id (primary key), name, symbol, address)
and later they will print admit card.

If they double enter their value and if there already exist an row for same value of symbol, I would like to update name and address to new value if there instead of inserting new one.

How can I do that..?

My Mysql Database is

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$symbol = $_POST['symbol'];
$address = $_POST['address'];



$sql = "
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM entrance WHERE symbol = :symbol)
INSERT INTO entrance(
name,
symbol,
address) VALUES(:name,:symbol,:address)
ELSE
 UPDATE entrance SET name = :name, address = :address WHERE symbol = 
:symbol
";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':name'=>$a,':symbol'=>$symbol,':address'=>$address,))
```

Comment: FYI https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

You could work with IF NOT EXISTS in your SQL.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM entrance WHERE symbol = :symbol)
  INSERT INTO entrance(
    name,
    symbol,
    address) VALUES(:name,:symbol,:address)
ELSE
  UPDATE entrance SET name = :name, address = :address WHERE symbol = :symbol
```

Comment: I have edited my question as you have suggested..is that the correct sequence?

Comment: Yes. That should work. Please change your question work, so that other people with the same question can make sense of this thread. Thank you!

Comment: Here is screenshot when I use IF NOt part then whole text is greyed out....is that expected or any should  I format my code in another way?  https://ibb.co/jGSZxxT

Answer (score 0):

First check if the data is in database by using select query

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM entrance WHERE symbol='$symbol'";
```

If select query return rows>0 then run update query else insert Query

Comment: @Romain can you please give me some details as Bastian has suggested, I formatted my code but now it greyed out...here is the image https://ibb.co/jGSZxxT. I have also updated my qeustion as per answer but it don't work which I think IF statement is not supposed be that way.